# How to create an event in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, events, serversocket

I am currently working on a multi-threaded socket based Java program that should allow multiple threads to send request to this program. This should be handled with the event activation but I am having hard time understanding events and their implementation. Below is the code that should allow more than 1 thread to communicate with the program but I only have 1 thread there. Can someone please shed more light on this? Much appreciated.

```
//this is a a threads class 
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Niti implements Runnable {

    public String line;
    public Socket soc;
    public boolean active=true;

    public Niti(Socket soc)
    {
        this.soc=soc;
        this.line=line;
        this.active=active;
    }


    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
            line=br.readLine();
            while(line!=null && !line.equals("")){

                if(!this.active)
                   break;

                System.out.println(line);
                line=br.readLine();
            }

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            bos.write("Poruka iz Programa".getBytes());

        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Niti.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {        
           soc.close(); 

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Niti.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}



import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


//and this is the main class
public class Server{


    public static synchronized void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1000);

        while(true){
            Socket sokit = ss.accept();
            Niti n = new Niti(sokit);
            while(true){

                Thread t = new Thread(n);
                t.start();

                //Thread.sleep(4000);
                //n.active=false;
                System.out.println("nit broj:" + Thread.currentThread().getId()); 
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. Do you want to pass some parameters to the new Thread?

Comment: Hi Ivan, I noticed that you catch the same 'IOException' twice in the same method. Although this does not make any difference, it would be best to use only 1 catch block for the same 'IOException'. This will make your code a little bit more tidy.

Comment: What I am trying to do is enable multiple threads to access this server instead of just one. If you put this code into your Net Beans it will loop through just one thread. Last I was told in order for multiple threads to be able to access the server I would need to create some events and listeners which could aid in resolving this matter. I don't know how to do this, do you have any idea on where I should start from? TY

Comment: You should probably remove the inner `while(true)` to enable your server to accept more than one client socket.

Comment: There are a lot of problems in your code, adding multiple threads will make it impossible to make grow or maintain. First thing about multithreading is that if you synchronize a method, it will never run in more than one thread, guaranteed. Also, you are initialising two variables in your constructor with the same value they already have, null (for line) and true (for active). And many more. Trully, forget threads for some months, or you'll regret it.

Comment: Assylias, you're write, it was a typo in the code so I removed the while(true) loop in question.

Igor, can you please reword the code so I can learn from your example? Please let me know of the way you would do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without look to Niti class (that is the client handler class as I suppose) you have a logic error here:

```
    while(true){
        Socket sokit = ss.accept();
        Niti n = new Niti(sokit);
        while(true){ // LOGIC ERROR!!!

            Thread t = new Thread(n);
            t.start();

            //Thread.sleep(4000);
            //n.active=false;
            System.out.println("nit broj:" + Thread.currentThread().getId()); 
        }   
    }
```

With the above code you are creating infinit Threads after pass the first time through accept method. What you have to do is to remove the second while(true), like this:

```
    while(true){
        Socket sokit = ss.accept();
        Niti n = new Niti(sokit);

        Thread t = new Thread(n);
        t.start();

        //Thread.sleep(4000);
        //n.active=false;
        System.out.println("nit broj:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());               
    }
```

Comment: That's correct, thanks for pointing it out. I cut out the while(true) loop in question and this works fine now.
Now, when I type in my browser http://localhost:1000/ the program prints out the request from my browser which it is supposed to do and every time I hit the refresh button page it prints out the same message. The problem is I need to have more than one thread in there. How to I create a logic that will allow for multiple threading which is what I originally wanted to build? Please advise. Tx

Comment: It still not clear to me where do you want more Threads. If you want more than one Thread to process the `Niti` class code, for example to do the `System.out.println(line);`, just create a new thread to process that, but, for the current logic, the code: `Socket sokit = ss.accept();` from `Server` class and the code: `line=br.readLine();` from `Niti` **must** run in only one Thread (realy one Thread for `Server` class and one Thread per client for `Niti` class). If its not that what you want to process in other Thread, then, try to make a more complete example and more close to the purpose.